# laravel scheduler for queue listening is not working without .env file in the elasticbeanstalk ec2.env is configured inside aws elasticbeanstack

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have to run `"php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run"` to listen the laravel queue in my elasticbeanstalk environment.As you may know, there won't be `.env` file inside e.b(elasticbeanstalk) ec2.
I have set all the env details in aws e.b configuration.But why my scheduler doesnt read .env from aws.
Sheduler is running.i can see the realtime logs but the queue only listens when .`env` exists.
**note**: It is working when i manually ssh to e.b ec2 and copy the `.env` file.
This is the actual command i have to run inside scheduler:

php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work database --queue=default

The following is my function for scheduler:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('live:session')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('app:remender')->daily();
        $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
    }
```

My `cron.config` in `.ebextension` is :

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root sudo chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
            * * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/log/schedule_run.log 2>&1       
commands:
    01-remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/schedule_run.bak"
```